# How can I make a solitaire game that can be solved?

Tags: procedural-generation, card-game

It was not difficult to mix the cards and make them in solitaire format.

But sometimes there are games that can't be solved. (For example in 3 turn mode)

How can I make sure that the game can be solved?

Answer (score 10):

Backtracking.

Start with a solved game. Then perform random valid moves in reverse until the game is in the initial state.

This usually works with any puzzle game.